# [help]ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-connection, mysql2

my rails environment is

Rails: 3.2.14,

ruby: 1.9.3,

system: ubuntu

mysql: 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

I create a mysql database,and to test the database, I connect It from my mysql workbench in windows.so, I want to show that,my mysql database in ubuntu is run correctly

but ,when I run the website in browser , I get the error: activerecord::connectionnotestablished .

the full trace is:

```
activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__72338529__call__445636797__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.14) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/hxh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/hxh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/hxh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

my `database.yml` is:

```yml
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: r4rmusic_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:123 
  host:127.0.0.1
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

my `Gemfile` is:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.14'
gem 'mysql2'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1' 

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

please help me

Comment: Please can you try by adding pool in database yml.

Comment: my `database.yml`  include ' pool: 5'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `host: localhost` and remove `socket` from `database.yml`

Comment: now I change my `database.yml` as set `host: localhost` and remove `socket`

but it still not work

Comment: thanks , I have solved my problem.the error is that `password:123` should be changed to `password: 123` need a space behined `password:`

Answer (score 0):

Remove socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock from database.yml only. It will work.

Comment: I Remove `socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` from database.yml ,but it not work,has any other error?

Comment: thanks, I have solved my problem.the error is that `password:123` should be changed to `password: 123` need a space behind `password:`